# How to locate a package installed by yum?

Tags: yum

I use `yum list php-imap` list the php-imap:

```
# yum list php-imap
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.zju.edu.cn
 * epel: ftp.cuhk.edu.hk
 * extras: mirrors.zju.edu.cn
 * updates: mirrors.zju.edu.cn
 * webtatic: sp.repo.webtatic.com
Installed Packages
php-imap.x86_64                        5.4.16-7.el7                        @epel
```

But how can I find the location of it? 
I know I can use `find / -name php-imap` for searching, but it is every long time, even the command do not have reactivity.

---

In my CentOS 7, the `/var/tmp/` is an empty directory. and list the `/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/` are:

```
base epel extras mysql56-community mysql-connectors-community mysql-tools-community timedhosts timedhosts.txt updates webtatic.
```

there is no `php-imap`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to know where the rpm file is, depending on your yum config your system may or may not keep it.  Check /etc/yum.conf (not sure this is the right location on ALL systems but on my Centos box this is the right place) for the line "cachedir=" and this will tell you where the cache of rpms is located.  For example:

```
grep cachedir /etc/yum.conf
```

My system says /var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasevar

In the same file, if keepcache=0 is included, your system will not save the rpms.  Change this to keepcache=1 to keep them around.  Depending on your storage space you might need to clean this up now and then.

If you want to know where the actual software is on your system, do this:

```
rpm -qa | grep php-imap
```

Then take the package name from the result (looks like it might be php-imap.x86_64) and do this

```
rpm -q --filesbypkg <package full name here>
```

Comment: This is correct for packages installed using `rpm` not `yum`!

Comment: `yum` uses the same RPM installation database as `yum`, so the query commands will work nevertheless.

Comment: rpm -ql {package name} could help to locate, such as

rpm -ql gperftools-libs-2.6.1-1.el7.x86_64
/usr/lib64/libprofiler.so.0
/usr/lib64/libprofiler.so.0.4.14
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc.so.4
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc.so.4.4.5
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_and_profiler.so.4
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_and_profiler.so.4.4.5
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_debug.so.4
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_debug.so.4.4.5
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_minimal.so.4.4.5
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_minimal_debug.so.4
/usr/lib64/libtcmalloc_minimal_debug.so.4.4.5

Answer (score 2):

Given that your question is about the packages installed using `yum`, then You have to check the options `info` and `list` "sub-flags". According to [Yum man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum.8.html):

```
       info           Display details about a package or group of packages 
       list   Is used to list various information about available packages;

        LIST OPTIONS
       The following are the ways which you can invoke yum in list mode.  Note that all list commands include information on the version of the package.

       OUTPUT

              The format of the output of yum list is:

              name.arch [epoch:]version-release  repo or @installed-from-repo

              Note that if the repo cannot be determined, "installed" is printed instead.

       yum list [all | glob_exp1] [glob_exp2] [...]
              List all available and installed packages.

       yum list available [glob_exp1] [...]
              List all packages in the yum repositories available to be installed.

       yum list updates [glob_exp1] [...]
              List all packages with updates available in the yum repositories.

       yum list installed [glob_exp1] [...]
              List the packages specified by args.  If an argument does not match the name of an available package, it is assumed to be a shell-style glob and any matches are printed.

       yum list extras [glob_exp1] [...]
              List the packages installed on the system that are not available in any yum repository listed in the config file.

       yum list distro-extras [glob_exp1] [...]
              List the packages installed on the system that are not available, by name, in any yum repository listed in the config file.

       yum list obsoletes [glob_exp1] [...]
              List the packages installed on the system that are obsoleted by packages in any yum repository listed in the config file.

       yum list recent
              List packages recently added into the repositories. This is often not helpful, but what you may really want to use is "yum list-updateinfo new" from the security yum plugin.
```

In Addition, the path to the installed packages depends on your system settings:

In Centos7

```
/var/tmp/yum-root-xxxxx/
```

or

```
/var/tmp/yum-username-xxxxx/
```

or

```
/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/program_name/packages/
```

In RHEL, the files are stored in

```
/var/cache/yum/x86_64/6Server/rhel-6-server-rpms/packages/
```

Comment: In my CentOS 7, the `/var/tmp/` is an empty directory. and list the `/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/` are: `base  epel  extras  mysql56-community  mysql-connectors-community  mysql-tools-community  timedhosts  timedhosts.txt  updates  webtatic`. there is no php-imap.

Comment: @fanhualuojin154873. Please see my edits above. Could be that your system was configured to remove the packages after installation. The response above is for packages installed by `rpm` your questions is about `yum`!

Comment: `yum` is not a stand-alone tool, but basically a higher-level user interface for `rpm`